# Drop unordered duplicates across separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

I am trying to return a `df` where duplicate values have been removed. I have tried to use `drop.duplicates()` but the values in the columns which have been `subset` aren't ordered. As in, the values are duplicates but they aren't in the same order.

For instance, using the `df` below, if I try to remove duplicate values from `Item_X` and `Item_Y` it will return the same `df`. Where the intended output will remove the second row.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Item_X' : ['Foo','Bar','Bot','Bot','Bar','Foo'],                 
    'Item_Y' : ['Bar','Foo','Foo','Bot','Bar','Foo'],                 
    'Value' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],                      
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Item_X','Item_Y'])
```

Expected Result:

```
  Item_X Item_Y  Value
0    Foo    Bar      1
2    Bot    Foo      3
3    Bot    Bot      4
4    Bar    Bar      5
5    Foo    Foo      6
```

Actual Output (Incorrect):

```
  Item_X Item_Y  Value
0    Foo    Bar      1
1    Bar    Foo      2
2    Bot    Foo      3
3    Bot    Bot      4
4    Bar    Bar      5
5    Foo    Foo      6
```

What would be the most efficient way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to sort the columns along the horizontal axis, then get a mask to subset the original frame. Here's how you can use `np.sort` and `df.duplicated` to do that:

```
df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df2[['Item_X', 'Item_Y']], axis=1)).duplicated()]

  Item_X Item_Y  Value
0    Foo    Bar      1
2    Bot    Foo      3
3    Bot    Bot      4
4    Bar    Bar      5
5    Foo    Foo      6
```

Comment: We are on the same track here. :D +1

Comment: @anky_91 Yup, the answer is identical (!) except I specify `axis=1` so it is obvious what it is doing.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, use:

```
m=pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['Item_X','Item_Y']])).duplicated()
df[~m]
```

---

```
  Item_X Item_Y  Value
0    Foo    Bar      1
2    Bot    Foo      3
3    Bot    Bot      4
4    Bar    Bar      5
5    Foo    Foo      6
```